# Prevent Choosing past hours from current hour in Datetime picker modal for android?

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I want to prevent choosing past hours from current hour in [`DateTimePickerModal`](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker). in `IOS` it works fine but on `Android` i can choose the past hours. How can i prevent that in [`minimumDate`](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#minimumdate-optional)?

My code is :

```js
<DateTimePickerModal
                style={{
                  width: 'auto',
                  marginBottom: 16,
                  backgroundColor: '#F0F3F4',
                }}
                isVisible={showDatePicker}
                mode="datetime"
                minimumDate={getTodayStringSuperior()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
minimumDate={new Date()}
```

Answer (score 0):

react-native-modal-datetime-picker documentation says, minimumDate only works for mode 'date' in android. Timepicker doesn't support this.